# add Object to useState() and show data in react native

Tags: typescript, react-native, state, hook, use-state

I have the following function:

```
const [dataLoc, setDataLoc] = useState({date: "No data received yet from sensor", coords: {}});
```

I set the location here:

```
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      location => {
        const date = dateToString(location.timestamp);
        const coords = location.coords
        setDataLoc({date, coords})
      }
)
```

With coords interface:

```
export interface GeoCoordinates {
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
    accuracy: number;
    altitude: number | null;
    heading: number | null;
    speed: number | null;
    altitudeAccuracy?: number | null;
}
```

From:

```
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';
```

I want to render the data like this:

```
<Text style={styles.data}>{dataLoc.coords.latitude}</Text>
```

But I receive:

```
error: SyntaxError: .../App.tsx: Unexpected token
```

I can't receive any properties of the object because the object is empty `{}` like I stated in `useState()`.

When I try to define the object in `useState()` I get an error because e.g. `altitude` can be a `number` or `null`.

My question is how can I add coords to dataLoc without defining it and still retrieving the object elements or defining it that some values can be a number or null?

I also tried to define it in `useState()` as:

```
const [dataLoc, setDataLoc] = useState({
date: "No data received yet from sensor", 
coords: { 
  latitude: 0,
  longitude: 0,
  altitude: 0,
  accuracy: 0,
  altitudeAccuracy: 0,
  heading: 0,
  speed: 0
}
});
```

But then I receive:

```
Type '{ latitude: number; longitude: number; altitude: number 
| null; accuracy: number; altitudeAccuracy: number | null; 
heading: number | null; speed: number | null; }' is not 
assignable to type '{ latitude: number; longitude: number; 
altitude: number; accuracy: number; altitudeAccuracy: number; 
heading: number; speed: number; }'.
Types of property 'altitude' are incompatible.
Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'number'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Comment: How are you bringing in `Geolocation`?

Comment: added the import and showed the ```interface``` from the npm package!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [dataLoc, setDataLoc] = useState<{
  date: string;
  coords: GeoCoordinates;
}>({
  date: '', 
  coords: {} as GeoCoordinates,
});
/*
 * Your another codes
 */

//calling it everwhere you want (e.g in useEffect)
const _setLocation = () => {
  //checking location permission then
  Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    ({timestamp, coords}) => {
      const date = dateToString(timestamp);
      setDataLoc({date, coords});
    },
    e => console.log(e),
  );
};
/*
 * Your another codes
 */
return (
  <Text style={styles.data}>
    {dataLoc.coords?.latitude}
  </Text>
);
```

Comment: I just added ```as GeoCoordinates``` and fixed the import to solve my problem!

Answer (score 1):

You need to be explicit about the type of your state value because it can't be inferred from the init value.

For example if your state value is a `number` type annotation is not required.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(0); // TypeScript infers the number type

setValue(53); // Ok
setValue('some string'); // Error
```

But let't say your value can be either a `number` or a `string`. It's impossible for TS to infer that from the init value because a value can't be simultaneously a `string` and a `number`. So we we pass the type to this [*generic*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `useState` function.

```
const [num, setNum] = useState(0); // TypeScript infers the number type
const [value, setValue] = useState<string | number>(0); // We explicitly pass string | number

setNum('some string'); // Error
setValue('some string'); // Ok
```

Now going back to your specific example, when you initialize your state like this.

```
const [dataLoc, setDataLoc] = useState({
  date: "No data received yet from sensor", 
  coords: { 
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0,
    altitude: 0,
    accuracy: 0,
    altitudeAccuracy: 0,
    heading: 0,
    speed: 0
  }
});
```

as shown in the error, this is the type that TS infers from that

```
{
  date: string;
  coords: { 
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
    altitude: number;
    accuracy: number;
    altitudeAccuracy: number;
    heading: number;
    speed: number;
  };
}
```

but that doesn't represent the reality, so you'd need to define the type or get it from the library and pass it to `useState`.

```
interface DataLoc {
  date: string,
  coords: { 
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
    accuracy: number;
    altitude: number | null;
    heading: number | null;
    speed: number | null;
    altitudeAccuracy?: number | null;
  };
}

const [dataLoc, setDataLoc] = useState<DataLoc>({
  date: "No data received yet from sensor", 
  coords: { 
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0,
    altitude: 0,
    accuracy: 0,
    altitudeAccuracy: 0,
    heading: 0,
    speed: 0
  }
});
```

That should solve the error. I'd recommend getting the correct type from the library instead of duplicating it as I did in the code snippet.